# Having an issue getting picture from my laptop to my tv

Tags: laptop, hdmi, tv

My laptop is connected to my HD TV using a HDMI cable. I was getting picture before my laptop had to restart. Now after the computer rebooted I am getting no video signal.

I checked the HDMI cables with another laptop and it works fine.

Im wondering if maybe the display settings were changed somehow. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to press a button or a combination of buttons, to enable to HDMI output or share your screen through that output. Which button or combination depends on your laptop's make/model.

A quick review of the different symbols printed on your keyboards, especially those "F" keys, Should reveal some clues. Failing that, refer to the user manual if you have it, or download one from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Many laotops have button combinations (eg. <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>) to enable and disable external displays. You should search your laptop's instruction book for something similar.

You might also be having problems because you don't have the additional display activated in Windows.

If you have Windows 7, you can press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or right click the desktop and choose display properties [to enable your TV as an additional monitor.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976064/en-us)